# (unknown SDK "flutter´")

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

not understand why not compiled my project in flutter, when compile it show this.
the path is good in the environment of variable the sdk of flutter is good

[teimprimimos] dart pub get
Resolving dependencies...
Because teimprimimos depends on flutter from sdk which doesn't exist (unknown SDK "flutter´"), version solving failed.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's a late answer but I encountered recently that's why answering here. In your **pubspec.yaml** where **spelling** of flutter **sdk** under **dependencies** or **dev_dependencies**.